# Maya python dynamically populate gridLayout while in use

Tags: python, maya, dynamic-loading

I need to add a lot of images(iconTextButton) to a gridLayout.
At this time it takes to long for the user to wait till all images are loaded.

I want to add them while the user can interact with the layout.
How to achieve this kind of dynamic loading?

```
import maya.cmds as mc
import time

class dynamicLoad():
    def __init__(self):
        #-- Window
        self.window_name = 'win'
        if (mc.window(self.window_name, exists=True)):
                mc.deleteUI(self.window_name)
        self.window = mc.window(self.window_name)

        #-- Layout
        layout = mc.formLayout(w=200)
        self.gridview = mc.gridLayout(
                numberOfColumns=4,
                cellWidthHeight=(50, 50),
                allowEmptyCells=False,
                autoGrow=True,
            )
        mc.showWindow( self.window_name )

        #-- Load buttons
        self.create_buttons()

    def create_buttons(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.load_button()

    def load_button(self):
        time.sleep(1) #-- Fake loading time
        mc.setParent( self.gridview )
        mc.iconTextButton( style='iconAndTextVertical', label='test')
dynamicLoad()
```

Comment: This can be tricky. If I understand it correctly, then your loadButtons display an image and the loading of the image takes so long? 

I fear with Maya builtin methods and python it can be quite tricky to load the images independently from the main thread.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, if its to complicated for Maya then I will build a system that loads a new array of buttons when scrolling. But that can still be annoying for the user I guess...
So the 'Threaded' loading would be a better solution :)

Comment: Why not creating small fast loading icons?

Comment: They are small. 64px per icon. In a early test with ~50 icons it slows down already. And maya doesn’t let me scale up images in the interface. So I can’t use smaller ones. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64632275/maya-python-scale-picture

Comment: 64px icons should be not take long. Even creating 50 icons should not take very long. Maybe it could help to first create the buttons and then show the window.

Comment: I would say you will hit the limitation from maya cmds api. You might be able to do so with PySide and some Threading. Still I agree with Haggi Key, 64px button even if they are 50 should not be really long and put self.create_buttons() before  mc.showWindow( self.window_name ) might save some refreshing time